# In R, what is the difference between ICCbare and ICCbareF in the ICC package?

Tags: r, correlation, icc

I am not sure if this is a right place to ask a question like this, but Im not sure where to ask this.

I am currently doing some research on data and have been asked to find the intraclass correlation of the observations within patients. In the data, some patients have 2 observations, some only have 1 and I have an `ID` variable to assign each observation to the corresponding patient.

I have come across the `ICC` package in R, which calculates the intraclass correlation coefficient, but there are 2 commands available: `ICCbare` and `ICCbareF`.

I do not understand what is the difference between them as they do give completely different ICC values on the same variables. For example, on the same variable, `x`:

`ICCbare(ID,x)` gave me a value of -0.01035216

`ICCbareF(ID,x)` gave me a value of 0.475403

The second one using `ICCbareF` is almost the same as the estimated correlation I get when using random effects models.

So I am just confused and would like to understand the algorithm behind them so I could explain them in my research. I know one is to be used when the data is balanced and there are no `NA` values.

In the description it says that it is either calculated by hand or using ANOVA - what are they?

Comment: Seems more appropriate as an email to the package author/maintainer?

Answer (score 0):

By: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ICC/versions/2.3.0/topics/ICCbare
ICCbare can be used on balanced or unbalanced datasets with NAs. ICCbareF is similar, however ICCbareF should not be used with unbalanced datasets.